# If, else, elseif - 4 conditions - shopify

Tags: if-statement, shopify, liquid

I'm working on rewriting the if statements for my collection page on shopify. I'm trying to get the item-price line to show the text 'out of stock' when the product is unavailable/when all variants are sold out. I can get the code working if it's under 3 conditions, but not sure how to add an additional condition.

the 4 conditions are:

if the product is on sale, show the price comparison

if the product price varies, show the lowest price

if the product and all variants sold out, show out of stock text

else, show normal pricing

I've tried a few different ways, below are what I'm stuck on...Any help is appreciated!
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2d5Z.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv7LE.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in liquid the else if syntax is `elsif` instead of `elseif`.

Try something like this `{% if x %} {% elsif y %} {% elsif z %} {% else %} {% endif %}`

Comment: oh my god, thank you, can't believe i missed that. for some reason I can only get the out of stock text to show on product with only 1 variant. 

 {%- elsif variant.available == false and variant.inventory_quantity == 0 -%}
<span class="ProductItem__Price Price Text--subdued">Out of Stock</span>

Comment: for your code to work, you would have to iterate through the variants of a product, like this `{% for variant in product.variants %}{{ variant.inventory_quantity  }}{% endfor %}`. For example, if you only have one variant, using something like this would work fine `{% if product.variants[0].available == false %}{% endif %}` or `{% if product.first_available_variant.available == false %}{% endif %}`, you don't need to check `.available` as well as `.inventory_quantity == 0` because they do the same thing. If you have multiple variants you need to plan how you display stock information.

Comment: this should be a helpful resource https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Objects-variant-is-not-working-and-data-is-not-shown-on-the-page/td-p/395518